# navigation bar doesn't appear correctly, through php echo

Tags: php, html, css, web

I'm sitting here in front of a problem, which is very unknown for me.

When I use normal HTML-Code everything works. When I use a php-echo, my navigation bar doesn't look normally.

The bar is supposed to look like this (here with normal HTML CODE):

http://i.gyazo.com/1e5c02f7e20dff5ec55800f259ff2c8f.png

and with php-echo it looks like this:

http://i.gyazo.com/693dd2a2ac7a333905e2aa90cc8cc147.png

and that's the code snip with HTML:

```
<div class="naviBar">
        <ul id="mainNavi">

            <li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li>
            <li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li>
            <li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

and here with PHP-ECHOs:

```
<div class="naviBar">
        <ul id="mainNavi">
            <?php
            echo "<li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li>";
           ?>
        </ul>
</div>
```

So after almost an hour I found the "error" and found a solution:

Instead of just echo, I used "\n" in the end of the line, like this:

```
   echo "<li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li>\n";
```

Why does it work here and not with normal echos? It is the first time I ever had this problem... What is wrong here?

I hope this code-snip is enough for now, if it isn't I'll add more of the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you properly ending the `</div>` in your php part ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen They are. OP missed an indent. Edited. We can delete these comments.

Comment: It should not make a difference since the CSS does not care about the EOL. If your resulting HTML is (without "\n", I prefer "\r\n"):
`<div class="naviBar"><ul id="mainNavi"><li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li><li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li><li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li></ul></div>` Sometimes it does. Did the CSS react the same way in all browsers?

Comment: @Fred -ii - Thanks for the Edit !!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you'd have to understand a little something about the way unordered lists operate.  The syntactic structure of your statement places each of the `<li>` items on the same line.  Also, of course you have to use a newline character `\n` or a `<br>` line break element.  Otherwise PHP (and HTML for that matter) doesn't distinguish where one line begins and ends, they'll just be run-on lines.  That's the beauty of PHP, and what provides it it's concatenation superpowers.

To fix your dilemma and correct the output so the `<li>` elements are partitioned as in your first screenshot, try including your `<ul>` tags in the echo statements as well.

Answer (score -2):

Because all your "echos" are being evaluated inside the same  tag.  As far as HTML is concerned, anything that happens inside those tags has no line returns in it.

You could have done this (but your way is better):

```
<?php echo "<li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li>"; ?>
<?php echo "<li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li>"; ?>
<?php echo "<li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li>"; ?>
```